# Shiny - textInput

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way that we can provide available options while using textInput in shiny similar to shiny selectinput option?

That is, if a user types a letter or character, all available options within the letter or character must be provided. Since I have a lot of options, selectinput kind of slows down and not a good option for the input. Therefore, I opt for textInput.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Probably selectize is what you need: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html

Comment: The answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265920/auto-complete-and-selection-of-multiple-values-in-text-box-shiny) might help you

Comment: To clarify some confusion: By default, selectInput() and selectizeInput() use the JavaScript library selectize.js. Unless you choose the basic input specifically on selectInput() with `selectize=FALSE`. So everybody is talking about different modes of `selectize` already. See [gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-vs-select.html) and [reference](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use selectInput with argument multiple = TRUE

```
selectInput(inputId, label, choices, multiple = TRUE)
```

This will output a text box rather than drop down and as user starts typing all the available options within the letter will be filtered.

[Create a select list input control](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html)

[Example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-vs-select.html)

Answer (score 2):

using DT, you can do some fancy stuff. Following is an example where the table lists all the options that contain the text you typed. If you click on a table cell, the text input is updated with the table cell's text. You can also use the search field of the table.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(textInput("text", "Please input text:"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),

  server = function(session, input, output) {

    # all your choices for the textfield go into "text" column
    allData <- data.frame(ID = '', text = c(paste0("Text",1:50)))

    # table with only the texts that contain input$text
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      allData[grep(input$text, allData$text), ],
      selection = 'none',
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(searchHighlight=T)
    )

    # fill textInput after Click in Table
    observeEvent(input$tbl_cell_clicked, {
      info <- input$tbl_cell_clicked

      if (is.null(info$value) || info$col != 1) return()
      else {
       updateTextInput(session, "text", value = info$value)
      }
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*selectinput kind of slows down and not a good option for the input*

`selectInput` with multiple choice is the best option in this case. The slow loading can be easily managed by moving `selectInput` into server.

Just type in `ui.R`:

```
selectizeInput(inputId=..., label=..., choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
```

and in `server.R`:

```
server <-  function(input, output, session) {
    updateSelectizeInput(session = session,inputId =...,choices=..., server = TRUE)}
```

**Now You should not have any problems with slow loading.**