# Editable value in Shiny selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a selectizeInput with X choices. My idea it should provide a sort of inputbox with X options but I want these choices to be editable. By this I mean if I select an option and I want edit part of it instead of being forced to click "backspace" or "delete" to clear the box, I want to be able to edit part of it. For example if I pick in the drop down box "New York" and I want to add "New Jersey", I should be able to pick "New York" and just replace the "York" with "Jersey" without the need to rewrite all the input.

I can't seem to find any option to do this since the delete everything seems to be the default behaviour.

Comment: You can use shinySky auto.complete... it s may be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265920/auto-complete-and-selection-of-multiple-values-in-text-box-shiny

Comment: Thanks, though I would rather not use external libraries

Answer (score 1):

Use selectize with:

```
selectizeInput(... options = list(create=TRUE, plugins = list('restore_on_backspace')))
```